# Dynamically Change Fusion Chart Value with Slider Event in flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, dynamic, slider, fusioncharts

I am having a set  of slider for each bar in the graph. I have bindded all the sliders with their corresponding bars. When i change the value of slider the value in the ArrayCollection changes and i have also used

> singleData.refresh();

but the values in the chart remains unchanged. How can i update the values in the chart with the change in values of the slider.

Here is my code:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.SliderEvent;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var singleData:ArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection([
               {label:'Diego', value:'22'},
               {label:'Steve', value:'20'},
        ]);

        private function updateChart(event:SliderEvent, index:Number):void{
            singleData.getItemAt(index).value = String(event.value);
            singleData.refresh();
        } 
    ]]>
</mx:Script>


<ns1:FusionCharts x="10" y="10" FCChartType="Column3D" width="500">  
    <ns1:FCChartData  FCParams="{chartParam}" FCData="{singleData}" />
</ns1:FusionCharts>

<mx:VBox x="10" y="318">
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Diego:" width="100"/>
        <mx:HSlider id="SliderDiego" change="{updateChart(event,0)}" liveDragging="true" value="{singleData.getItemAt(0).value}" minimum="0" maximum="100" width="120"/>                    
    </mx:HBox>
    <mx:HBox>
        <mx:Label text="Steve:" width="100"/>
        <mx:HSlider id="SliderSteve" change="{updateChart(event,1)}" liveDragging="true" value="{singleData.getItemAt(1).value}" minimum="0" maximum="100" width="120"/>                    
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charts do not retains the binding after rendering. In update chart function set the new data again and render chart. Before that also set an id to the chart.

```
<ns1:FusionCharts id="FC1" x="10" y="10" FCChartType="Column3D" width="500">
```

Now in script do this:

```
private function updateChart(event:SliderEvent, index:Number):void{
        singleData.getItemAt(index).value = String(event.value);
        singleData.refresh();
        FC1.FCData(singleData);
        FC1.FCParams(chartparam);
        FC1.FCRender(); 
}
```

Referenced from : http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/docs/charts/Contents/case_changeData.html